# Jansson build errors

Tags: linux, build, jansson

I am pretty new to Linux and I am having problems integrating an external software into my program. When I am following the instructions on integrating a couple of lines that includes Jansson (Add G4Sipm to your CMakeLists.txt in this document [enter link description here](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/g4sipm/latest/g4sipm.pdf)) I get errors which I suspect is the problem of integration itself since it does separately build on its own. The errors I get are after command `build -j2`. Here is a part of the terminal output:

```
Scanning dependencies of target jansson
Scanning dependencies of target gtest
Scanning dependencies of target G4GeneralParticleSource
[  1%] Building C object externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/CMakeFiles/jansson.dir/src/dump.c.o
[  2%] Building C object externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/CMakeFiles/jansson.dir/src/error.c.o
[  2%] Building C object externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/CMakeFiles/jansson.dir/src/hashtable.c.o
[  3%] Building CXX object G4BasicObjects/G4PropertyFileReadInTools/CMakeFiles/G4PropertyFileReadInTools.dir/src/PropertyToolsManager.cc.o
[  4%] Building C object externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/CMakeFiles/jansson.dir/src/hashtable_seed.c.o
[  4%] Building CXX object G4BasicObjects/G4PropertyFileReadInTools/CMakeFiles/G4PropertyFileReadInTools.dir/src/GoddessProperties.cc.o
[  4%] Building CXX object G4BasicObjects/G4PropertyFileReadInTools/CMakeFiles/G4PropertyFileReadInTools.dir/src/VectorUtil.cc.o
[  5%] Building CXX object externals/g4sipm/externals/googletest/googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.o
[  6%] Building C object externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/CMakeFiles/jansson.dir/src/load.c.o
[  6%] Building C object externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/CMakeFiles/jansson.dir/src/memory.c.o
[  7%] Building C object externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/CMakeFiles/jansson.dir/src/pack_unpack.c.o
[  7%] Building C object externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/CMakeFiles/jansson.dir/src/strbuffer.c.o
In file included from /home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/src/hashtable.h:11,
                 from /home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/src/jansson_private.h:11,
                 from /home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/src/dump.c:12:
/home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/src/jansson.h:101:22: error: unknown type name ‘json_int_t’; did you mean ‘json_t’?
  101 | json_t *json_integer(json_int_t value);
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                      json_t
/home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/src/jansson.h:280:1: error: unknown type name ‘json_int_t’; did you mean ‘json_auto_t’?
  280 | json_int_t json_integer_value(const json_t *integer);
      | ^~~~~~~~~~
      | json_auto_t
In file included from /home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/src/hashtable.h:11,
                 from /home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/src/jansson_private.h:11,
                 from /home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/src/error.c:1:
/home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/src/jansson.h:101:22: error: unknown type name ‘json_int_t’; did you mean ‘json_t’?
  101 | json_t *json_integer(json_int_t value);
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                      json_t
/home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/src/jansson.h:288:39: error: unknown type name ‘json_int_t’; did you mean ‘json_auto_t’?
  288 | int json_integer_set(json_t *integer, json_int_t value);
      |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                       json_auto_t
In file included from /home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/src/dump.c:12:
/home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/src/jansson_private.h:60:5: error: unknown type name ‘json_int_t’
   60 |     json_int_t value;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/src/jansson.h:280:1: error: unknown type name ‘json_int_t’; did you mean ‘json_auto_t’?
  280 | json_int_t json_integer_value(const json_t *integer);
      | ^~~~~~~~~~
      | json_auto_t
/home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/src/jansson.h:288:39: error: unknown type name ‘json_int_t’; did you mean ‘json_auto_t’?
  288 | int json_integer_set(json_t *integer, json_int_t value);
      |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                       json_auto_t
In file included from /home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/src/error.c:1:
/home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/src/jansson_private.h:60:5: error: unknown type name ‘json_int_t’
   60 |     json_int_t value;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/src/hashtable.h:11,
                 from /home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/src/hashtable.c:19:
/home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/externals/jansson/src/jansson.h:101:22: error: unknown type name ‘json_int_t’; did you mean ‘json_t’?
  101 | json_t *json_integer(json_int_t value);
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                      json_t
```

I tried adding `#include <jansson_config.h>` instead of `#include "jansson_config.h"` however errors still persisted. I tried contacting the project lead however it seems they have all moved on from the project. Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Edit 1: for clarification, I am using the latest version of Jansson

Comment: Are you including jansson.h as recommended in the [Jansson documentation](https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/2.8/apiref.html#preliminaries)?

Comment: Hello, yes I am, some of the errors actually occur in Jansson.h itself.