# Build errors when trying to integrate external package

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, cmake, build

I am pretty new to Linux and I am having problems integrating an external software into my program. I am following the instructions on integrating a couple of lines that show step by step integration of the software they are listed in the [Application development section here](https://g4sipm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/application_development.html#add-g4sipm-to-your-cmakelists-txt).

I got through some of the instruction [I removed Jansson] and I have separately tested the package independent and build it thus it works outside. The problem is when intergrating  after `make install` command it shows these errors:

```
    Scanning dependencies of target g4sipm_sample
[ 63%] Building CXX object externals/g4sipm/sample/CMakeFiles/g4sipm_sample.dir/src/ActionInitialization.cc.o
/home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/sample/src/ActionInitialization.cc: In member function ‘virtual void ActionInitialization::Build() const’:
/home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/sample/src/ActionInitialization.cc:45:38: error: no matching function for call to ‘RunAction::RunAction(const string&)’
   45 |  SetUserAction(new RunAction(filename));
      |                                      ^
In file included from /home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/sample/src/ActionInitialization.cc:21:
/home/abhinab1/goddess/source/Simulation/include/DataProcessing/RunAction.hh:35:2: note: candidate: ‘RunAction::RunAction(SimulationMessenger*)’
   35 |  RunAction( SimulationMessenger * simulationMessenger   /**< class storing and providing variables which are needed in different parts of the simulation. */
      |  ^~~~~~~~~
/home/abhinab1/goddess/source/Simulation/include/DataProcessing/RunAction.hh:35:35: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const string’ {aka ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’} to ‘SimulationMessenger*’
   35 |  RunAction( SimulationMessenger * simulationMessenger   /**< class storing and providing variables which are needed in different parts of the simulation. */
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/abhinab1/goddess/source/Simulation/include/DataProcessing/RunAction.hh:26:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr RunAction::RunAction(const RunAction&)’
   26 | class RunAction : public G4UserRunAction
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
/home/abhinab1/goddess/source/Simulation/include/DataProcessing/RunAction.hh:26:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const string’ {aka ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’} to ‘const RunAction&’
/home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/sample/src/ActionInitialization.cc:46:20: error: no matching function for call to ‘EventAction::EventAction()’
   46 |  SetUserAction(new EventAction);
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/sample/src/ActionInitialization.cc:20:
/home/abhinab1/goddess/source/Simulation/include/DataProcessing/EventAction.hh:38:2: note: candidate: ‘EventAction::EventAction(SimulationMessenger*)’
   38 |  EventAction( SimulationMessenger * simulationMessenger   /**< class storing and providing variables which are needed in different parts of the simulation. */
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/abhinab1/goddess/source/Simulation/include/DataProcessing/EventAction.hh:38:2: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
/home/abhinab1/goddess/source/Simulation/include/DataProcessing/EventAction.hh:30:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr EventAction::EventAction(const EventAction&)’
   30 | class EventAction : public G4UserEventAction
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/abhinab1/goddess/source/Simulation/include/DataProcessing/EventAction.hh:30:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
/home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/sample/src/ActionInitialization.cc:52:57: error: ‘const class DetectorConstruction’ has no member named ‘getSipmModel’
   52 |  ParticleSourceMessenger::getInstance()->setA(detector->getSipmModel()->getPitch());
      |                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/abhinab1/goddess/source/externals/g4sipm/sample/src/ActionInitialization.cc:53:57: error: ‘const class DetectorConstruction’ has no member named ‘getSipmModel’
   53 |  ParticleSourceMessenger::getInstance()->setB(detector->getSipmModel()->getPitch());
```

Here are the changes that I made in my CMakeFile.txt:

```
add_subdirectory(externals/g4sipm)                                  
include_directories(externals/g4sipm/g4sipm/include)              
include_directories(externals/g4sipm/externals/gtest/include)      




# Export sims data

include_directories(externals/g4sipm/sample/include)
set(LIBS ${LIBS} boost_program_options g4sipm g4sipm_sample boost_date_time jansson)

target_link_libraries(RunSimulation g4sipm boost_date_time)
```

I tried contacting the project lead however it seems they have all moved on from the project. Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

EDIT: I made a small mistake as I added

```
include_directories(externals/g4sipm/sample)
```

in the Checklist.txt which I removed.
The errors are reduced but not gone I have put the updated terminal output above.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Perhaps, Jansson is necessary? Why did you remove it?

Comment: Hi thank you for responding, since Jansson was the one causing build errors earlier I couldn't figure a way around it (refers to the previous question I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63307105/jansson-build-errors ) and since it is used as an option to export simulation data I opted for optional support ROOT package (which I have installed).